# My computer goes to sleep for no reason while I'm using it

Tags: 11.10, mouse, hibernate, taskbar

My computer will go to sleep for no reason. It did so two minutes ago while I was using my mouse to navigate the Internet. It had power.

Also, sometimes I am suddenly unable to select anything in a workspace, or bring up the side bar when I move the cursor to it.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 on an HP.

Comment: What happens when it goes to sleep? Does it respond to activity and come back out of sleep ok?

Comment: Voting for closing since there has been no answer and very little information to help with... unless John comes up!